# Binary Search Tree does not add to the right of the root

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree

I am writing a templated binary search tree class, the function I use to create the binary search tree is the following:

```
void insert(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> * & t)
    {
        if (t==NULL)
            t = new BinaryNode<Comparable>(x, NULL, NULL);

        else if (x < t->element)
            insert(x, t->left);
        else if (x>t->element)
            insert(x, t->right);
        else
            ; // Duplicate; 
    }
```

and BinaryNode is another templated class as the following:

```
template <class Comparable>
class BinaryNode
{
public:
    Comparable element;
    BinaryNode *left;
    BinaryNode *right;

    BinaryNode(const Comparable & theElement,
        BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt)
        : element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt) { }
};
```

The problem is, whenever I create a new tree, it adds the first element as the root. Then even if the next element I want to add is greater than the root it adds to the left of the root. For the elements on the left of the tree, this problem does not occur, it propoerly adds it to the right whenever necessary. Can you help?

EDIT: Problem solved. I was reading a file line by line and storing those lines into nodes, it turned out that the getline gets the first line of the file in a way that it starts with weird characters-even though there exists none. Those characters always had a greater value from other normal letters, thus it always goes to the left of the tree.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a [mcve]? If you get it to compile on e.g. https://godbolt.org or https://wandbox.org then you'll most likely get a good answer.